# Cannot scrape this site with requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to scrape some of the tables of [this web site](https://coriolis.io/outfit/fer_de_lance?code=A4pktfFalfdpsff30x27272727040404040404B2-2b27m1m1.AwRj4yvI.Aw18WQ%3D%3D.H4sIAAAAAAAAA42SvS9DYRTGTz%2B1vW1v79VWBfXRi8TQNLYabKIDibGryWLoQMQi7AYRwWAwGA1GQ2OyNjEYDCL%2BCBN1jueIvmmbSu5N7pMn7%2Fm9zz335BAPEdF3BNI%2BhVgnAaLUYZLI2YNz7y0irxkkkgAvG%2FIAEtv4ErHfy0T5uzDIJwRJkPMG2oHY3qdItggyd20TFZQsNUZAhnjMkPtKPlf%2BQrKvOCzVPkQkzIsdyK7son65hKsRrpqrR5B4kkUSZw7RtLoZdbPq5tRJlDc7uJuZJypr9OjaBEox3jJJRUikjqaityl8X5uQONdNHS%2BF9Xf6oYQfyPIDJbug0H9QilcMdKWD0VNXp1N4jBNNvqQBpf1Ath8ow7UeyGpgsI6Kd5xA3eHV3vpNFEm6G4663yRPnbhdSRcDkoZ53dS3IcFCWySqG2NVMQ3nDZLTnrymrlqOFwx%2BrnEPsOmpcZDqXN03T53k%2B8mWIVuGVCdCg54fTavTLSQDAAA%3D.EweloBhAOEoUwIYHMA28QgIwV3fEQA%3D%3D). When I do the requests, the html returned is different than the one in the browser.

I tried to inspect the browser Network tab to see if there is any json response that fills the info but couldn’t find any. I realized that the html returned by requests is the one present in the html doc showed in the Network tab (in the browser inspector), that as I said, is different by the one showed in the Elements tab (the one shows the full html code I want).

I know I am missing something and would appreciate if you could explain me how this websites works:

- ¿Why is the response different?
- Is there any chance of achieve this without the use of real browsers (I prefer not using selenium for efficiency purposes).

This is my code

```
url  = 'https://coriolis.io/outfit/fer_de_lance?code=A4pktfFalfdpsff30x27272727040404040404B22b2b27m1m1.AwRj4yvI.Aw18WQ%3D%3D.H4sIAAAAAAAAA42SvS9DYRTGTz%2B1vW1v79VWBfXRi8TQNLYabKIDibGryWLoQMQi7AYRwWAwGA1GQ2OyNjEYDCL%2BCBN1jueIvmmbSu5N7pMn7%2Fm9zz335BAPEdF3BNI%2BhVgnAaLUYZLI2YNz7y0irxkkkgAvG%2FIAEtv4ErHfy0T5uzDIJwRJkPMG2oHY3qdItggyd20TFZQsNUZAhnjMkPtKPlf%2BQrKvOCzVPkQkzIsdyK7son65hKsRrpqrR5B4kkUSZw7RtLoZdbPq5tRJlDc7uJuZJypr9OjaBEox3jJJRUikjqaityl8X5uQONdNHS%2BF9Xf6oYQfyPIDJbug0H9QilcMdKWD0VNXp1N4jBNNvqQBpf1Ath8ow7UeyGpgsI6Kd5xA3eHV3vpNFEm6G4663yRPnbhdSRcDkoZ53dS3IcFCWySqG2NVMQ3nDZLTnrymrlqWFwx%2BrnEPsOmpcZDqXN03T53kfJP5frJlyJYh1YnQwOcHDPQx9E8DAAA%3D.EweloBhAOEoUwIYHMA28QgIwV3fEQA%3D%3D'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
s = requests.Session()
n = s.get(url,verify=False,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(n.content,'html.parser')
tables = soup.find_all(class_='group half') # Present in the browser but not in the returned request
```

Comment: try the html2text module

Answer (score -1):

Please use python selenium in order to scrap the site.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

url  = "your site url"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get(url)
page = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
....
```

Scraped responds might be different by options of header, but selenium will respond same response like as opening site via real browser.
And you can use `option.add_argument('--headless')` in selenium without opening browser.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I as I told I am looking for a solution without using selenium. If there is a way to achieve it I would like to learn it